# Order Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, multisets

I understand order and repitition of elements does not matter when talking about sets. However, multisets have it so repitition of elements does matter. Is there another specific type of set where order matters?

Comment: I've adjusted the tags - "elementary-set-theory" is more appropriate for this type of question, and [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) refers to a specific subfield of mathematical logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) is a finite ordered list of elements.  [Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) do not care about order, just about how many of each element there are, so as multisets $\{1,1,2\}=\{1,2,1\}.$  Sequences can be finite or infinite but care about order.